# Как сортировать значения столбца в датафрейме с несколькими точками

Tags: python, pandas

В датафрейме df есть столбец 'index', который выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хотел отсортировать столбец 'index' по пунктам. Использовал такой метод:

```
df.sort_values(by='index'))
```

но на выходе получил:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю, что когда сортирую столбец, то значение 1.1.1.11 считается меньшим за 1.1.1.9, хотя должно быть наоборот.
Подскажите, как решить эту проблему? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Нужно найти или написать функцию, которая будет правильно подготавливать эти строки к сортировке. Я написал. Суть в следующем:

- разбиваем строки по точке на отдельные элементы
- пустые элементы (например, после последней точки) выкидываем
- не пустые элементы преобразовываем в числа
- делаем из получившегося списка чисел кортеж
- а дальше питон и `Pandas` уже сами умеют правильно такие кортежи сортировать

Код:

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['1.1.1.','1.1.1.11.','1.1.1.9.','1.2.']

def prepare2sort(x):
    return [tuple(map(int, filter(None, i.split('.')))) for i in x]

df = pd.DataFrame({'data': data})
df.sort_values('data', key=prepare2sort)
```

Вывод:

```
    data
0   1.1.1.
2   1.1.1.9.
1   1.1.1.11.
3   1.2.
```

Answer (score 2):

можно попробовать вот такой, правда довольно громоздкий, вариант сортировки по ключу:

```
df.sort_values('data', key=lambda x: pd.Series(x).apply(
                           lambda s: tuple(map(int, s.strip('.').split('.')))))
```

Comment: О, я знал, что можно как-то `apply` сделать на `Series`, но сходу не сообразил, как это сделать, как правильно лямбду написать, а их тут оказывается нужно две )

Comment: Интересное решение! Я пытался понять зачем здесь `pd.Series(x)` и понял, что он здесь не нужен ) По-моему, можно заменить `pd.Series(x)` -> `x`

Comment: @MaxU, вы абсолютно правы